# Can a mask hide only one object and not the others?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

I want to make the word "SECRET" disappear behind the horizon. That is, I need a mask for the lower half of the image, but if I do this, it also hides the sea..! How can I accomplish this?

[image: Titles]

Comment: How did you apply the mask? Have you tried to use the mask strip modifier?

Comment: @Ectras I did ; I made a PNG image with the top half transparent, I also tried with a "color" strip, and various combinations of the Mask Modifier ; but no matter what I try, the sea disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay, I figured it out:

- Using the UV/Image Editor, create a mask, and give it a meaningful name;
- Select the "SECRET" text strip ; Its "Blend" should be "Alpha Over" that's the default for text strips anyway, leave it at that;
- Add a "Mask" modifier and select your newly created mask by its name.

[image: Masking]